# nativescript extend jar class throw exception

Tags: android, nativescript

i use nativescript + tyepscript need extend android jar but it throw exception say
“Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.”

```
declare var com : any;

export class MyPushTestReceives extends 
com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushMessageReceiver.extend {
static constructorCalled: boolean = false;

// //constructor
init() {
    MyPushTestReceives.constructorCalled = true;

    // necessary when extending TypeScript constructors
    return global.__native(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either the TypeScript class extend syntax, or the JavaScript way of calling `.extend({})` on the Java class, but not both.

Therefore dropping the unnecessary .extend should solve your problem:

```
export class MyPushTestReceives extends com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushMessageReceiver
```